# link error __stack_chk_fail (using libs with xcode)

Tags: c++, xcode, linker-errors

I'm trying to compile a C++ app in xcode using gcc 4.0 and and the 10.4u SDK.

I get the following linker error.

"**_stack_chk_fail", referenced from:
      _read_frame_ in libAudioDecoder.a(stream_decoder.o)
      _read_metadata_ in libAudioDecoder.a(stream_decoder.o)
  "**_stack_chk_guard", referenced from:
      ___stack_chk_guard$non_lazy_ptr in libAudioDecoder.a(stream_decoder.o)
     (maybe you meant: ___stack_chk_guard$non_lazy_ptr)
ld: symbol(s) not found

Other help threads suggest that all I need to do is add...

-fno-stack-protector

...to the 'Other C Flags', which is what I've done, but the problem persists. I've done cleans, rebuilds and even restarted XCode (because it's been known to get confused sometimes), but the problem persists.

Note that libAudioDecoder is my own library that I'm trying to link with. stream_decoder.o is apart of the FLAC library which libAudioDecoder links to.

Essentially my project links with libAudioDecoder which links with libFlac, where libFlac has also been compile using an xcode project.

For each three xcode projects, I'm using gcc 4.0 and and the 10.4u SDK and have 'Other C Flags' and 'Other C++ Flags' set with -fno-stack-protector.

I'm all out of ideas at the moment, so would appreciate some help with this.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Symbol `_stack_chk_fail` is referenced from symbol `_read_frame_` in your `libAudioDecoder.a` library, not the Xcode project from which you are linking against `libAudioDecoder.a`.  Try to go back and rebuild `libAudioDecoder.a` with the `-fno-stack-protector` flag?

It sounds like you may have compiled the library linking against a newer version of `libc` and are now compiling with an older version, or some other mismatch like that.  Searching for "`_stack_chk_fail`" on StackOverflow will lead you to a ton of other tips.

Comment: All the projects, including libAudioDecoder are using the -fno-stack-protector flag. I'll try and widen my search for some libc related topics. Cheers.

Comment: This is a very late reply to my own post (I resolved this issue a while ago now), but I think the problem was because I still had equivalent library files inside /user/local/lib. I thought I'd got rid of them a long time ago, but sure enough, they were there again and XCode always seems to give them priority over anything that I explicitly set in the build options.

Comment: Change the order of `-L` arguments to the linker to alter priority.  Directories are searched for libraries in the order they are listed, and then the system-wide libraries are searched.